# Https Post in objective c

Tags: objective-c, http, post, nsurlsession

I have the below code for http post request,

```
FIRDatabaseReference *agreementCreateReference = [[[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"/agreements/"] childByAutoId];
NSLog(@"autoId %@",agreementCreateReference.key);
NSLog(@"autoId %@",_propertyId);
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"agreementId=%@&listingId=%@",agreementCreateReference.key,_propertyId];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://krib-api-onbit.herokuapp.com/api/agreements"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:idToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-FIREBASE-ID-TOKEN"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSLog(@"%@",request);

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"data dtat %@",data);
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

This url with parameters and headers returns data in the Postman. When I use to get data using objective c using the above code I get `<42616420 52657175 6573740a>` as data. And not calling the backend either.

Comment: replace `NSLog(@"data dtat %@",data);` with `NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"res %@",res);`

Comment: `NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` with (`<42616420 52657175 6573740a>`) means `Bad Request`. What's the doc about it? Did you try with POSTMAN ? What about `NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"agreementId":agreementCreateReference.key, @"listingId": _propertyId} options:nil error:nil];`?

Comment: No, this is not returning anything or printing anything in the server. In the Postman it is returning data and printing the request in the server.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on this issue, I just sent the parameters via the URl and it returned data and printed the request in the backend. Code is as follows for anyone.

```
FIRDatabaseReference *agreementCreateReference = [[[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"/agreements/"] childByAutoId];
                        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://krib-api-onbit.herokuapp.com/api/agreements?agreementId=%@&listingId=%@",agreementCreateReference.key,_propertyId];
                        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
                        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                        [request setValue:idToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-FIREBASE-ID-TOKEN"];
                        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                        //[request setHTTPBody:postData];
                        NSLog(@"%@",request);

                        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
                        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"data dtat %@",data);
                            NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                            NSLog(@"res %@",res);
                        }];
                        [dataTask resume];
```